# Преобразование массива double в complex

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, я пытаюсь преобразовать массив double в массив complex, как мне говорили ранее, в действительной части мы записываем значения массива double, а мнимую часть присваиваем нулю. Я создал структуру Complex в проекте, объявил конструктор, который в качестве параметра принимает re (массив double), а мнимую часть присваивает нулю, дальше когда я с помощью метода пытаюсь преобразовать массив double в complex и результат возвратить в переменную signal, результат пока не возвращается, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём у меня проблема?

```
public struct Complex 
{    
     // переменная, хранящая реальную часть комплексного числа            
     private double[] m_real;

     // переменная, хранящая мнимую часть комплексного числа
     private double m_imag;

     public Complex(double[] re)
     {
         m_real = re;
         m_imag = 0.0;
     }  

     // Свойства устанавливающие значения
     public double[] Re
     {
         get { return m_real; }
         set { m_real = value; }
     }

     public double Im
     {
        get { return m_imag; }
        set {m_imag = value; }
     }

     //Метод преобразующий массив double в complex
     public Complex[] ConvertToComplex(Double[] data)
     {
        Complex[] signal;
        Complex c1 = new Complex(data);
        signal = c1;
        return signal;
     }
}`
```

Comment: Комплексное число состоит из одной реальной части и одной мнимой. Почему у вас в `Complex` хранится `double[] m_real`, а не `double m_real`?

Comment: @Regent, понял, я исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод конвертирования массивов лучше сделать статическим, так как он по логике будет являться частью состояния типа Complex, а не экземпляров этого типа:

```
//Метод преобразующий массив double в complex
public static Complex[] ConvertToComplex(Double[] data)
{
    Complex[] signal = new Complex[data.Length];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        var value = data[i];
        Complex c1 = new Complex(value);
        signal[i] = c1;
    }


    return signal;
}
```

а еще лучше - воспользоваться неявным оператором преобразования:

```
public static implicit operator Complex(double value)
{
    return new Complex(value);
}
```

Конструктор вашей структуры будет выглядеть так:

```
public Complex(double re) : this()
{
    Re = re;
    Im = 0.0;
}
```

---

В случае использования неявного оператора преобразования теперь можно писать так:

```
double[] doubleArr = ...
Complex[] complexArr = ...
for (var i = 0; i < doubleArr.Length; i++)
{
    complexArr[i] = doubleArr[i];
}
```